# UV mapping fill brush paint rendering different colour

Tags: uv, image, uv-image-editor

I am trying to add an image to a cube but only part of it. I set up a UV map where I selected a single face of the cube and split it into different segments twice. I selected the centred segments and unwrapped them and then loaded my image. The image is centred where it should be but the background colour of the image (yellow) bleeds through to the rest of the object. I then selected the remaining faces using Texture paint select everywhere and try to fill it as white. The object looks okay when in the default viewport but when I render the image it is still yellow.

Does someone know what is wrong with my method or of another way by which to do what I want?

Thanks,
Paul.

Comment: *"The object looks okay when in the default viewport but when I render the image it is still yellow"* did you save the image after painting with white? (note to not overwrite original image if it's needed). Texture will be applied to all faces which are present on UV map so either don't unwrap those which aren't required, assign them to different material or use mask image which will cover areas with unneded parts of the texture.

Comment: In the end up I realised I could just map the image to a plane and sit the plane over the face of the cube where I needed it to be. Just for posterity though in the example of my question: I had a cube, I selected one face, then segmented it twice so that it had 4 segments in the middle I could select. Taking the centre four segments only I unwrapped them; I then selected the image I wanted to wrap which was a yellow sign with a warning. The warning contents mapped nicely to where I wanted them but the rest of the object turned yellow as well.